# What does the Clothier (or any) voodoo doll do?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Somewhere I found a Clothier Voodoo Doll; What does it do other than enable you to kill the Clothier? Does it summon the WoF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you equip the Clothier Voodoo doll in an accessory slot it allows you to kill the Clothier. If you kill the Clothier at night you will summon Skeletron.

The Guide Voodoo doll when destroyed by lava in the underworld summons the Wall of Flesh.

Comment: Note however that dropping the Clothier Voodoo doll in lava will not do anything.

Comment: Also note that the Guide Voodoo Doll can also be equipped as an accessory, allowing you to damage and kill the Guide. This won't, however, summon the Wall of Flesh, which can only appear when the doll is destroyed in lava in the Underworld.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you drop the doll into lava, it kills clothier, summoning skeletron, but does nothing else.

Comment: Hi @user272974 and welcome. The accepted answer already includes information about dropping the doll into lava, but it says so for the Guide doll. Can you confirm that the accepted answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Clothier Voodoo Doll, when equipped, allows you to kill the Old Man/ Clothier, summoning Skeletron. Note this only happens at night, while the guide Voodoo Doll can be equipped to kill the guide, allowing you to get Luigi's Cap, for some odd reason, but can also be sacrificed to the lava in the underworld/Heck. It summons the ultimate pre-Hardcore boss, the Wall of Flesh.

Note that if you drop the Clothier Voodoo doll into Heck's lava, it does not spawn Skeletron nor the Wall of Flesh.